# check_snmp_mem.pl Icinga2 configuration broken

Tags: icinga2

I can successfully run

```
check_snmp_mem.pl -v -H kvm.lala.bo -l bravo -x th3r4m1N+ -X j4bAdeHu5 -w 50,70 -c 80,90
```

but configuring "snmp-memory" check in Icinga2 is not working. 
Here's what I have in the config file for kvm.lala.by:

> ```
> check_command = "snmp-memory"
> host_name  = "kvm.lala.bo"
> vars.snmp_v3 = "true"
> vars.snmp_warn = "50,70"
> vars.snmp_crit = "80,90"
> vars.snmp_perf = "true"
> vars.snmp_login = "bravo"
> vars.snmp_password = "th3r4m1N+
> vars.snmp_v3_use_privpass = "true"
> vars.snmp_privpass = "j4bAdeHu5"
> ```

Icingaweb2 keeps printing

> Can't mix snmp v1, 2c, 3 protocols! Usage:
>   /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_snmp_mem.pl [-v] -H  -C
>    [-2]

Comment: The remote host I'm trying to monitor is not made reference to anywhere but in /etc/icinga2/conf.d/lala.conf.

Answer (score 1):

Not using the plugin, but I guess the problem is `snmp_community` having a default value. Please try setting it to `false`.

Comment: That's a good idea.

Comment: Actually this directive (snmp_community = "false") seems to have been ignored. I still see the same error.

Comment: Perhaps 
`snmp_community = ""` 
will work.

Comment: `false` would be a literal, when you define it as string/text, it will be the value of the community...

Comment: I tried `snmp_community = false` and that failed as well.

Comment: "false" is the default when snmp v3 is specified, according to the docs.